# iOS: how to change current UIViewController from custom singleton class

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, singleton

I have a common trouble but can't find a right way to solve it, I'll start from beginning.

I'm making a game app with game center and matchmaking. I want to receive and handle invitation from friends. I made singleton class that handle all the Game Center stuff. Right now, I'm in doubt about how to handle invitations (I mean in entire app).

My singleton does handle it and I made additional protocol that calls a delegate method when invitation has been received. So, I decide to implement this protocol in all of my UIViewControllers (I don't know how to do this in a better way, if you know I would very appreciate if you share your experience). But now, I'm stuck with a problem that is in a title. I need to change my UIViewController from current view controller to "game view controller" (it must be shown for the game). I use Navigation View Controller for my app. 
So, is there a way to change current view controller to a particular view controller from my "Game Center stuff" singleton class or at least from current ViewController?

For example, I'm in options view controller, that is come from main menu view controller(MainMenuVC→OptionsVC) and I'm receive invitation and I'm accept it. Right now I want to go to "game view controller or GameVC", that is places in another segue path (MainMenuVC→Game ModesVC→GameVC).

I hope my question is clear, if not, I'll provide images to explain, just let me know in the comments below. I think that this question is quite trivial and there are some common practices. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the issue exactly, but have a look at UINavigationController:setViewControllers: and see if it might be what you are after. 
It will allow you to swap one stack of view controllers for another stack.  To create your new stack you can use [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"whatever"]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your need is the notification.

add this to OptionVC, after you accept invitation, send this message:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AcceptInvitationNofity" object:self];
```

and add this to your MainMenuVC:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receiveEvent:)
                                                 name:@"AcceptInvitationNofity"
                                               object:nil];
```

in receiveEvent function, navigate to GameVC.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 questions from what I've read. Correct me if I'm wrong.

1st question, you're asking if there's a better way to handle a singleton that deals with background stuff such as invites and etc.

So right now, you have a singleton with delegation in every single controller. We don't know if what these delegates do and how specializes they are to your controllers. Since it's in all controllers, I suspect that all controllers have to do mostly the same things once the delegation is called? In that case, you should have a BaseController that implements the delegation methods and have all subsequent controllers be a subclass of that BaseController. Any specialized logic can be overridden in the subclass and [super delegateMethod] can be called.

---

2nd question is you're asking if you can go from one segue stream to another segue stream within the same UINavigationController. That one is easy. You need to give your Controllers on the storyboard an identifier, instantiate those controllers using the identifier, put it all into an array, then set the navigationcontroller's Controller array to that new array. Here's some code to illustrate that.

```
-(void)someButtonPressed {
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers].mutableCopy;
    [viewController removeLastObject];
    [viewController addObject:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GameModes"]];
    [viewController addObject:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GameVC"]];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
}
```

This will pop your current view controller and make you land on the GameVC controller while preserving the GameModes controllers.

Comment: you are right, my singleton handle all Game Center things like authentication, sending and receiving invitations, matchmaking. And I want to change my current ViewController (whatever it is) to my game view controller (where player accept invite). So, you are right, and I'll try to implement your decision.

Answer (score 0):

After having received an invitation, you can call this from your current UIViewController:

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GameVCIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

where "GameVCIdentifier" is the identifier of the UIViewController you want to show. You can set the identifier inside your Storyboard.